# DotNetNuke 5: How do you edit module content in DotNetNuke 5?

Tags: dotnetnuke

How can I edit modules in DNN5? I have previously used DNN4. It is not obvious to me what to do now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't anything that has changed substantially between DNN 4 and DNN5 in terms of editing module content.  First, make sure that you're logged in with a user who has edit permissions to the module.  Then make sure that you're viewing the site in Edit mode (the radio buttons on the top left).  Then, there will probably be an "action menu" in the top left corner of the module's container, from which you can access the module's edit page.

If you're still having trouble, it may be that you're using a container that doesn't have the standard action menu.  You can try changing the container for the page or the site (in page or site settings) to see if that addresses the issue.

Finally, which module are you trying to edit content in?  Is it an HTML module, or some other module?